# Raise black point on windows display

Tags: display, calibration

Alright, this might be impossible due to the monitor range. But I’m not sure so I’ll ask here.

I’ve set my monitor to as close as I can to my laptop screen which is really good unlike the monitor(actually small TV) which is a few years now.

So after fiddling around with tv display settings and windows calibration I have achieved a pretty similar look, BUT the black areas seem too black and a lot of detail in dark areas are missing.

Is there a way I can raise black point in Windows display settings? I can’t decrease contrast and brightness it just looks worse.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for the *gamma* setting.

Search for "*gamma*" in the Start menu (open it and type `gamma`). *Calibrate display color* should be suggested. Use it to adjust gamma to your needs.